# Integrating $\int\frac{-3}{x^2+4}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the problem: $\int\frac{-3}{x^2+4}\ dx $

I am unsure how to integrate it. It seems to me that it requires a u-substitution because of the $x^2$ in the denominator, but I cannot figure out what to substitute. I cannot substitute in $x^2$ because then I am stuck with an *x* in that derivative.
I do know that I can pull the -3 out of the integral and get: $-3\int\frac{1}{x^2+4}$ but this does not help me - I'm still stuck. I also know that arctan is $\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx$ which seems similar to this, but it is not the same thing.

Comment: Divide by $4$ and define $y = x/2$ then solve as an arctan

Comment: Let $x=2 \tan(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t = \dfrac x2\implies x = 2t,\mathrm dx = 2\mathrm dt$.

Therefore,

$$\int\dfrac {-3}{x^2 + 4}\,\mathrm dx = -\int\dfrac 6{4t^2 + 4}\,\mathrm dt = -\int\frac6{4(t^2 + 1)}\,\mathrm dt = -\frac 32\int\frac1{t^2 + 1}\,\mathrm dt$$

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac 1{t^2 + 1}\,\mathrm dt$ results in $\arctan t + C$. Reverse substitution to get
$$\int\dfrac {-3}{x^2 + 4}\,\mathrm dx = -\dfrac32\arctan\left(\dfrac x2\right)+C.$$

Comment: I can't follow how that substitution works. Can you break it down really simply - between $\int\dfrac {-3}{x^2 + 4}\,\mathrm dx$ and $-\int\dfrac 6{4t^2 + 4}\,\mathrm dt$

Comment: Substitute $x=2t$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner what do you mean?

Comment: If $x=2t$ then $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{-3}{x^2+4}dx=\int\dfrac{-3}{(2t)^2+4}2dt$; I thought that's what you were asking for

Comment: @Burt Which part are you stuck at?

Comment: I don't understand how to put $\frac x2$ in as a substitution when there is no $\frac x2$ in the problem.

Comment: @Burt ah, I see what you mean. You'd need some practice to figure out what substitutions are needed in what place. For this problem, you can look at it in the following way:
$\displaystyle\int\frac{-3}{x^2+4}\,\mathrm dx=-\frac32\int\frac{1/2}{(x/2)^2 + 1}\,\mathrm dx$.
Now, this expression is similar to something that you have in your original post. What happens when you substitute $\dfrac x2$ with $t$?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, $\tan^{-1}$ is a great start.

So once you have $\displaystyle -3\int \frac{1}{x^2+4}\,dx$, you can turn this into $\displaystyle -\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{2})^2+1}\,dx=-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{(\frac{x}{2})^2+1}\,dx$.

You see the perfect u-substitution yet?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int{\frac{-3dx}{x^2+4}}=-3\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+4}}=-3\int{\frac{dx}{4\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+1\right)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

-3/2arctanx/2 is a primitive function of -3/（x^2+4）.
It is easy to check this because （-3/2arctanx/2）’＝-3/（x^2+4）